# How do you deploy an application, in OpenShift, that listens on port 80 with a service that uses port 8080?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am having a hard time understanding Kubernetes networking and would like someone to explain it a little simpler than the documentation does.

My test service is below and contains all that I understand so far about ports and networking in Openshift/Kubernetes.
It is returning a 503 right now.

```yaml
# A Service can map any incoming port to a targetPort. 
# By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` 
# is set to the same value as the port field
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  ports:
    - name: HTTP
      # port is the stable port the Service exposes inside 
      # the cluster — other Pods in the cluster send traffic
      # to this port
      port: 5000 
      protocol: TCP
      
      # if you don’t specify a targetPort value, 
      # it defaults to the value specified in port

      # targetPort is the port that the container, 
      # within the Pod, listens on for incoming traffic.
      targetPort: 80 
      selector:
        app: my-app
```

```bash
route.yml - targetPort: 80
deployment.yml - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read out the tiny code snippets under my Github account to get familiar with K8S networking in nutshell: https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/05-Services

The lab will describe in detail exactly what you are asking.

- You can also print out the information (which you already know I assume)

```bash
kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.ports
```

---

To answer your question:

- The easiest way to "find" out what is going on is to use CLI to create the resources and examine the output

```bash
# Create ns
kubectl create ns codewizard

# Create the deployment
kubectl create deployment \
        nginx             \
        -n codewizard     \
        --image=nginx

# Create the service
kubectl expose deployment \
        nginx             \
        -n codewizard     \
        --port 5000       \
        --target-port 80  \
        --type ClusterIP  # default

# Check the service
kubectl get svc -n codewizard -o wide

# check to verify that the pod is connected
kubectl get      endpoints -n codewizard
kubectl describe endpoints -n codewizard
```

[image]

---

## Lets see the output

#### Service

```bash
# Get the service yaml 
kubectl get svc nginx -n codewizard -o yaml
```

```yaml
### Partial...
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
```

#### Lets try to test our network

```bash
# Create the 2nd deployment for our test
kubectl create deployment \
        multitool         \
        -n codewizard     \
        --image=praqma/network-multitool

# Lets get the pod name so we can test the connection to nginx
POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods          \
                 --no-headers      \
                 -n codewizard     \
                 -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" \
                 | grep multitool)

# Test the connection 
kubectl exec -n codewizard $POD_NAME -- curl -svL nginx:5000
```

[image]